# Is Selenium 2.42.2 webdriver compatible with Firefox 27.0.1?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Is Selenium 2.42.2 webdriver compatible with Firefox 27.0.1? If not, then which Firefox version is it compatible with?
I am using Selenium 2.42.2 webdriver. The test code that I wrote is:

```
public class SeleniumIntro {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl() + " "
                + driver.getPageSource());

        driver.close();
    }
}
```

When I run this, Firefox starts and then nothing happens. I have a hunch that its a compatibility issue. BTW, I have tried the latest version of Firefox also but with the same result. I can use some help or guidance here. Thanks.

Comment: What you see in console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please refer to the CHANGELOG [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG):

Selenium 2.42.0 supports to Firefox 29, which means that only the following four FF versions are supported:

- Firefox 29, the current FF release when this Selenium was released
- Firefox 28, the previous FF release
- Firefox 24, the current FF ESR release
- Firefox 17, the immediately previous ESR release

Selenium 2.42.1 and Selenium 2.42.2 were just providing bugs fixes unrelated to Firefox.

Therefore, to your question, nope, Selenium 2.42.2 doesn't support Firefox 27.0.1 officially. (This may not necessarily mean that Selenium 2.42.2 isn't compatible with Firefox 27.0.1, but I highly recommend you to upgrade your Firefox to 29)

Comment: where did you found that notes @YiZeng? I clicked the link but seems the readme is not showing that information.

Comment: @gumuruh: Link updated. Selenium is no longer hosted on Google code, so it's been redirected.